# How to solve ValueError: Cannot reshape error of size in object detection?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm working on tensorflow object detection api i'm have an issue with reshape array of size xxx into shape (2208,2688,3)

my image size is 2208 2688 
i tried with less size also 360 360 i'm encountering same issue

```
def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
```

Can anyone help me with this why am i getting that error and how to solve it

Comment: what type is `image` in the example? A  byte array of the image? it's filepath? Some image processing library representation of an image?

Comment: also: what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: image type is jpg

Comment: i'm seeing the following error
  File "<ipython-input-63-81ae31a6be09>", line 7, in <module>
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)

  File "<ipython-input-62-31ab332e9f1d>", line 4, in load_image_into_numpy_array
    (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5935104 into shape (2208,2688,3)

Comment: the image is of type jpg but what did you do to populate the `image` variable? Did you just read the file from the filesystem?

Comment: softmail412@gmail.com this is my mail id if you mail me i can share my code and dataset

Comment: The error was caused by wrong image channel numbers. The original image has one channel (shape 2208*2688*1) and you want to reshape it to three channel (2208*2688*3). The proper function maybe you are looking for is resize? You want to resize the image to a smaller size for object detection?

Comment: yeah i tried with 360 360 image size  also but i got the same number i trained grey scale images which right channel number for grey scale @danyfang

Comment: you should use a function like `resize` (like in opencv there is a `resize` function, `import cv2 as cv; cv.resize(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use a library to read the image into a numpy friendly format.

For example:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img_in_np_format = np.asarray(Image.open('/path/to/image.jpg')).astype('uint8')
```